# How to override selected color in theme override for material ui for react

Tags: reactjs, tabs, overriding, material-ui

I would like to override the selected text color for all tabs in [material ui for React](https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/).  I know I can override some portions with code such as this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        color: '#000000',
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        '&:hover': {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(108, 130, 168, 0.11764705882352941)',
          color: '#000000',
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

followed by

```
 <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <HomePage/>
 </MuiThemeProvider>
```

However, when the tab is selected it applies a class such as '.MuiTab-textColorPrimary-144.MuiTab-selected-146'.  How can I specify a global override color for textColorPrimary for the Tab component when it is selected?  I'm specifically interested in a global override and not an individual instance override.  Lacking a specific way for the Tab component, how would I specify a global override for 'selected' primaryTextColor?

Answer (score 15):

CODE:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTabs: {
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: orange[700]
      }
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: pink[100],
          color: pink[700]
        }
      },
      selected: {
        backgroundColor: orange[100],
        color: orange[700],
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: green[100],
          color: green[700]
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

LIVE EXAMPLE:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mj9x1zy4j9

Comment: This is an awesome answer and is an example of why we all love stackoverflow.  Adding a codesandbox link is really icing on the cake and is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: nice to know it helped, especially since i'm less than a week into react+mui frontend dev :)

Comment: I've asked a related question about setting height of material-ui Toolbar in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52043271/how-to-over-ride-an-media-css-for-a-material-ui-react-component

Comment: See upgraded syntax below for latest version of Material-UI

Comment: Lamber's note below is correct.  The example above needs to be updated.  Now the selected selector needs this format.  Note the dollar sign.

'&$selected': {backgroundColor: 'brown'}

Answer (score 4):

The CodeSandbox example in the accepted answer no longer works in the latest version of MUI (3.9.1) and when I try to fix the issue with the suggested change, it gives yet another error message.  See screen captures below.  See solution below.

[image]

[image]

eps1lon showed me how to do this on this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w71yvp96ml).
This should now be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another way could be:

```
MuiTab: {
  styleOverrides: {
    root: {
      color: `${colors.neutral30} !important`,
      '&.Mui-selected': {
        color: `${colors.secondary} !important`,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: This works but adds a second set of styles for root.Mui-selected

Comment: This works at MUI version 5.14.0. Thank you!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

In order to override the `selected` rule, you need to use the `$ruleName` syntax.
The rule override should be inside the root definition:
([Forked code sandbox with the fixed syntax](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui3-how-to-override-tab-theme-forked-m6z76?file=/demo.js:882-1082))

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTabs: {
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: orange[700]
      }
    },
    MuiTab: {
      root: {
        "&:hover": {
          backgroundColor: pink[100],
          color: pink[700]
        },
        "&$selected": {
          backgroundColor: orange[100],
          color: orange[700],
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: cyan[500],
            color: green[700]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: This works and updates the existing style

Answer (score 1):

also possible to use TabIndicatorProps

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {
      backgroundColor: "#D97D54"
    }
  }}
>
...
</Tabs>
```

if you need none-indicator

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTabs: {
      indicator: {
        backgroundColor: `transparent`
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the selected to the root node Like this:

```
  const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
      MuiTab: {
        root: {
          "&:hover": {
            backgroundColor: pink[100]
          },
          selected: {
            backgroundColor: orange[100]            
          }
        },
      }
    }
});
```